# How to fix not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Scan error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I get the following error when trying to use dynamodb scan:

> "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when
>   calling the Scan operation: User:
>   arn:aws:sts::747857903140:assumed-role/CodeStarWorker-helpbot-Lambda/awscodestar-helpbot-lambda-FindService-1L7IH17742JLR
>   is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Scan on resource:
>   arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:747857903140:table/HelpBot"

This is in my SAM template:

```
FindService:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: find_service.handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      Role:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Join ['-', [!Ref 'ProjectId', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'LambdaTrustRole']]
      Policies:
        - AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this SAM CloudFormation doc](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md):

> Policies - Names of AWS managed IAM policies or IAM policy documents or SAM Policy Templates that this function needs, which should be appended to the default role for this function. **If the Role property is set, this property has no meaning.**

You'll need to either define a role for the function that includes both groups of permissions and use that as the "Role", or add the LambdaTrustRole's permissions to "Policies".

The latter would look something like this:

```
  Policies:
    Version: '2012-10-17'
    Statement:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
      - dynamodb:Scan
      Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account-id:table/table-name
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
      - ...
      Resource: ...
```

Comment: Did you also remove the Role, since Policies won't take effect if Role is present?

Comment: It worked when I added the "AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess" permission from the IAM console.

Answer (score 0):

You need add new permission to your invoker (such as lambda-function or ...) like this(for example I have two table):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
           ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:77777:table/order"
            },
           {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:777:table/ExecutionId"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:777777:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:777777:log-group:/aws/lambda/MyReport:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```